# Aid with SQL SUM()?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am not sure if I am supposed to use SUM() for this, but I wanted to get the sum of all the values in the "earnedcoins" column and this is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(earnedcoins) FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$earnedcoins = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
echo $earnedcoins;
$conn->close();
```

Unfortunately, it just stamps out number 1. Can anybody help me resolve this issue? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @Dave `$result` is an object, you need to fetch it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_num_rows()` will always return `1` for that query, as you only get one row returned - which is the number of summed rows. Instead, you need to fetch that value from `SUM()`.

Give the `SUM()` an alias, and fetch the value. You should also use `GROUP BY` when using aggregate functions like `SUM()` - I don't know your table-structure, but perhaps `GROUP BY id` if that exists.

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(earnedcoins) as result FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$sum = $result->fetch_assoc()['result'];
echo $sum;
$conn->close();
```

Comment: No, it won't be `always 1`. It can still fail. The error handling in OPs code is non existing